# Проблема c #include C++

Tags: c++

у меня есть два класса Player и MapEditor , в классе Player я использую MapEditor, а в MapEditor я использую Player. Я забыл как называется это проблема но когда я пишу в Player.h , #include "MapEditor.h", а в MapEditor.h я пишу #include "Player.h", то у меня весь error list забит ошибками типо syntaxis error 'MapEditor' , undeclared identifer, также это мелочь конечно но подсветка синтаксиса в классах перестаёт работать. Кто нибудь знает в чем проблема?

TileMap.h -

```
  #ifndef TILEMAP_H
#define TILEMAP_H



#include "Tile.h"



class MapEditor
{
private:
    void clear();

    float gridSizeF;
    unsigned gridSizeU;
    sf::Vector2f maxSizeWorldGrid;
    sf::Vector2f maxSizeF;
    sf::RenderWindow * window;
    unsigned layers;
    std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < Tile*> > > map;

    sf::RectangleShape TileSet;
    sf::RectangleShape collisionBox;

    sf::Texture textureSheet;
    std::string textureFile;

    sf::Vector2i pixelPos;
    sf::Vector2f pos;

    void initTextures();
    void initTileSet();
public:
    MapEditor(sf::RenderWindow * window,std::string textureFile);
    virtual ~MapEditor();

    void addTile(const unsigned  x, const unsigned y, const unsigned z, sf::IntRect& textureRect,const bool collision,const short type);
    void removeTile(const unsigned  x, const unsigned y, const unsigned z);

    sf::Texture &getTextureSheet();

    void saveToFile(const std::string filename);
    void loadFromFile(const std::string filename);

    void checkCollision(Player * player);

    const sf::Vector2f & getMapSize() const;
    const unsigned & getLayerCount() const;

    const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Tile*> > >& getTiles() const;

    void update(float time);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow& window);


};



#endif // ! TILEMAP_H
```

Player.h -

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "Entity.h"


class Player {
protected:
    AnimationManager anim;
    float posX, posY, dx, dy;
    float speed;
    enum MovementDirection {
        STAY,
        LEFT,
        RIGHT,
        JUMP,
        TOP,
        DOWN
    };
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    MovementDirection state;

    bool playerOnGround;



    bool life;
    unsigned hp;


public:
    Player(float x, float y, sf::Texture & texture,  std::string anim_file);
    virtual ~Player();

    const bool& checkLife() const;

    void movement(float time);
    void checkCollision(float Dx,float Dy);

    const sf::FloatRect& getRect() const;

    virtual const sf::Vector2f& getPosition() const;

    void update(float time);

    void render(sf::RenderWindow * window);
};


#endif //CATCHONBUBBLE_PLAYER_H
```

Comment: Используйте, например, `#pragma once`, но это может не спасти, если ваши .h-файлы составлены неверно... Без конкретного кода трудно сказать что-то более точно.

Comment: Я добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: Не обращайте внимание на  #include "Tile.h" и "Entity.h", в них include-ы в Entity.h - #include "MapEditor.h", в Tile.h - #include "Player.h", просто проект большой много файлов приходиться как то выкручиваться

Comment: В `Player` я лично `MapEditor` не вижу. Так что достаточно включить Player.h в MapEditor.h. Обратное не требуется. Если, конечно, вы все показали :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть проблемы: при использовании директивы `#include` компилятор вставляет код из включаемого файла туда, где эта директива прописана. Если у Вас используется такое взаимное включение, как описано в вопросе, возникает неявная рекурсия: один файл включает другой, который вновь включает первый, а тот, в свою очередь, снова включает второй и т.д. Это приводит к множественному переопределению всего, что объявлено в этих файлах.

Такая проблема обычно решается выполнением следующих шагов:

1. Необходимо всё объявления классов оставить в `.h`-файлах, а реализацию всех методов вынести в одноимённые `.c`/`.cpp`-файлы
2. Далее, при необходимости взаимного включения, нужно делать его не в `.h`, а в `.c`/`.cpp`-файлах. Например, в файл `X.cpp` написать `#include"Y.h"`, а в `Y.cpp` написать `#include"X.h"`
3. Если в объявлениях классов (в `.h`-файлах) встречаются имена классов из включаемых файлов, необходимо прописать там `class Название_класса;`, что даст понять компилятору, что этот класс объявлен где-то ещё

Также следовало бы добавить, `#pragma once` в начале `.h`-файлов. Это не спасает от представленной проблемы, но спасёт от множества потенциальных.

Меня такая инструкция не раз спасала от проблем, подобных описанной в вопросе.

В представленном коде пункт №1, по всей видимости, уже выполнен.

Comment: Спасибо , 3 пункт помог, а первый я всегда так делаю , мне так приятнее

Comment: @SemyonDyachenko Всегда рад помочь. Если Ваша проблема решена, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ, как решение.

Comment: @V-Mor, `pragma once` не является стандартной (если так можно выразиться) директивой препроцессора, хотя и поддерживается большинством компиляторов. Используйте [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).